# Nativescript ListView [object Object]

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I'm new at `Nativescript` and I'm trying to use `ListView` with vanilla javascript. I have a weird error where the output in `ListViews` shows as `[object Object]` instead of an actual value.

> JSON response

```
[
    {
        passenger: "John Doe",
        category: "Arrival"
    },
    {
        passenger: "Martin Schulz",
        category: "Departure"
    },
    {
        passenger: "Giovanni Marocco",
        category: "Arrival"
    }
]
```

> Controller

```
var view = require("ui/core/view");
var http = require("http");

exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;

    http.getJSON("http://demo4727937.mockable.io/test").then(function (r) {
        page.bindingContext = {
            'myItems': r
        }
    }, function (e) {
        //// Argument (e) is Error!
    });

};
```

> Template

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ myItems }}">
            <ListView.itemTemplate height="50">
               <Label text="{{passenger}}" textWrap="true" class="title" />
               <Label text="{{category}}" textWrap="true" class="title" />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
         </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

> Result
>   [image]

Comment: you need to wrap your labels in a container e.g <StackLayout></StackLayout>

Comment: thanks @OseiFortune, it work. please consider posting this as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you need to wrap you template in a view container e.g StackLayout or even a GridLayout

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ myItems }}">
            <ListView.itemTemplate height="50">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label text="{{passenger}}" textWrap="true" class="title" />
                    <Label text="{{category}}" textWrap="true" class="title" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```